# OnDestroy not working properly UNITY 2D

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, 2d, ondestroy

I am currently having problems with the OnDestroy function. I have 3 Classes, PickUp, AddGold and Player where PickUp and AddGold is  component on the same prefab.

When my character collide with a treasure the PickUp script destroys it. The AddGold should then start a function in the Player class.

PickUp:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
     if (other.gameObject.tag=="Player") {
         Destroy (this.gameObject);
     }
```

AddGold:

```
 public Player playerScript;
 public int gold;

 void onDestroy(){
     playerScript.addGold (gold);
 }
```

And Player has this function in it

```
public void addGold(int gold){

     goldAmount += gold;
 }
```

Why doesnt this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Method is called

```
void OnDestroy()
```

with an *O* instead of an *o*